# Inputting textfile into list of class objects, then output the list contents

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of my current project, I am trying to load the contents of a text file into a list of class objects, then output the objects.  On a cursory look my instructor said my code looked fine, but there is no output.  I press enter, and...nothing.  It's not even printing the "Loaded" code.  It just prompts for a new input as if I pressed enter with no instructions.  I don't know if the objects are even being properly loaded into the list, and I'm thinking they are not.  I am only using the Windows console to run this, so debugging is limited and slow.

I am brand new to Python but this is not a python course, it's algorithms. But it is required that our projects be written in Python, so I'm learning as I go.  I usually code in C, C++, or Java.  What I've learned, I've taken from here and some helpful tutorials my instructor gave me.  I've searched here, but a lot of the code I see looks like what I have. So, I ask you very smart people...

What am I missing here?  Did I load the file into memory incorrectly?  Is the print line incorrect?  Anything else I'm overlooking?

Any help would be most appreciated.

UPDATE: It's running, thanks to the good people below, but now I'm getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\CPSC335\Project_2\project2.py", line 28, in 
>       main()   File "D:\CPSC335\Project_2\project2.py", line 24, in main
>       packages.append(DebianPackage(*line.split())) TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'votes' and 'size'

So, it looks like I'm loading the pulling the data from the text file incorrectly.  Is it a problem where the line splits?

CMD Input:

```
C:\Python34>python D:\CPSC335\Project_2\project2.py D:\CPSC335\Project_2\packages.txt 5
```

filename: packages.txt

```
debianutils 128329 90
libgcc1 128327 46
dpkg 128294 2672
perl-base 127369 1969
debconf 121503 168
grep 121426 595
gzip 121346 142
login 121332 980
coreutils 121240 6505
bash 121229 1673
```

CODE: project2.py

```
import sys

class DebianPackage:
    def __init__(self, name, votes, size):
        self.name = name
        self.votes = votes
        self.size = size
```

CODE: project2.py  (UPDATED based on great help below)

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print('error: you must supply exactly three arguments\n\n'+
            'usage: python3 <Python source code file> <text file> <n> <W>')
        sys.exit(1)

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    n = int(sys.argv[2])

    lines = open(filename).readlines()
    print('Loaded "' + filename)

    packages = []
    for line in lines:
        packages.append(DebianPackage(*line.split()))
    for package in packages:
        print(package.name + ' ' + package.votes + ' ' + package.size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a class and a function named main() in your module but not called it. So call it after definition. Put it at the end:

```
main()
```

There is other problems in your code. Your constructor name must be:

```
def __init__(...)
```

It's better to use readlines() in place of read():

```
lines = open(filename).readlines()
```

And use lines in for loop. So your code will be something like this:

```
import sys

class DebianPackage:
    def __init__(self, name, votes, size):
        self.name = name
        self.votes = votes
        self.size = size

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3: 
        print('error: you must supply exactly two arguments\n\n'+
            'usage: python3 <Python source code file> <text file> <n> <W>')
        sys.exit(1)

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    n = int(sys.argv[2])

    lines = open(filename).readlines()
    print('Loaded "' + filename)

    packages = []
    for line in lines:
        packages.append(DebianPackage(*line.split()))

    for package in packages:
        print(package.name + ' ' + package.votes + ' ' + package.size)

main()
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. But now it's saying that "TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'votes' and 'siz '" at (*line.split()). Shouldn't there be something to tell it where the line is to be cut for the new element in the object? That's why I had " " to denote a space. I mean, it doesn't work with that either, but that's where the console is noting the problem. Thanks so far, btw.

Comment: The split() has withe space as default value. So when you call it without argument, it uses white space as split character.

Comment: To debug such errors it's better to split line in a list before putting it in constructor. So, put (parts = line.split()) before calling packages.append(...) and check length of parts and values in it (by printing) to see if the problem. Sometimes empty lines and malformed lines in text files is the Evil!

Comment: I tested above code (mine) and it works fine with your sample. So, I think there is something wrong with your input files or you forget to use my last edited code.

Comment: That's the problem!  I feel stupid about that one. lol I fixed the offending line, and I got my output of objects.  Thanks a lot!!   One last thing though, even though the list output, I still got the following error afterwards: 
  File "D:\CPSC335\Project_2\project2.py", line 29, in main
    for package in packages:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"    Any thoughts?  I think it's something I can live with though, so long as it doesn't screw with my algorithm implementation (not mentioned here) later in the project.

Comment: For accessing elements of list (one or multiple) you have to use brackets []. When you use parentheses with list, this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your script to run, when you execute it by `python myapp.py`, put or call your main logic by this way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**UPD:**

And your class is incorrect, you should use `__init__`, not `_init_`:

```
class DebianPackage:
    def __init__(self, name, votes, size):
        self.name = name
        self.votes = votes
        self.size = size
```

Comment: Wow, that's a great catch.  I don't think I'd had ever noticed that unless I went back and rewrote it. lol  Thanks.